# service worker is not removed after uninstalling PWA app in angular

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I have created PWA app using angular. It works fine after installing app. Now I open website and login into website and credentials for that user is stored in localStorage. I click on add to home screen and open PWA app, it works fine. Then I uninstall app and again go to website and enter login credentials of other user. Then again I click on add to home screen icon and open PWA app but it shows me old user login instead of new which I did from website.

Steps:
-> Open Website and login as **User1**
-> Click on add to home screen 
-> Open installed PWA app it will show **User1** as logged in
-> Uninstall PWA app
-> Go to website and logged in as **User2** 
-> Click on Add to home screen 
-> Open installed PWA app it will show **User1** logged in instead of **User2**

User credentials are stored in localStorage from which website shows that which user is logged in the website

How can I show always new user as logged in, in the PWA app ?
Are service worker also unregistered after uninstalling PWA app from android, ios ?

Comment: hi, Welcome to SO. Please Read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It would be very good for you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented login auth through localstorage then until you log out from user1 , it will always show user1 logged in as it is stored in your localstorage in mobile. You have to logout from user1